# What is the name of the rvest robot? (i.e. How do I know if it's disallowed on robots.txt?)

Tags: r, web-scraping, robots.txt, rvest

I am using rvest to scrape some webpages and I understand that I should always look at the site's robots.txt file to know if I am allowed to scrape it or not. The problem is many sites' robots.txt files, such as [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/robots.txt), list many different bot names.

I'm a newbie to webscraping, so what is rvest's robot name and how do I know if it is allowed or not? Obviously if the site says

```
User-Agent: *  
Disallow: /
```

Then I know that all robots are prohibited from scraping, but what about when specific bots are named?

Comment: The short answer is that there are no clear rules, and the server you are trying to scrape from has all the authority to accept, reject, or terminate the conection. 
Robots.txt is still a very informal "institution", and there is no authoritative list of robots. Rvest wraps around the curl and httr packages-libraries, and neither has a robot name, beyond the one you could give them. 
In fact, the server does not recognize the "robots", albeit it might recognize the user agent.
Rcurl user agent is something like "libcurl/7.37.1 r-curl/0.9.1 httr/1.0.0".

Comment: There _are_ clear rules. You should set it to *your* bot name. If you're not popular enough to be in a `robots.txt` then you fall under the `*` ruleset and must obey that unless you negotiate with the site offline. Contact them and _do not_ abuse other's bot names. Ever. You should also use a generic "Mozilla"-ish user-agent or one that embeds your bot contact info. Source impersonation is not cool for a bot without negotiating with the target site.

Comment: Do you know how to set the bot name / user-agent for rvest then? (I'm not quite familiar with the right term)